# Geocode address, using Google (not geocoder)

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

Can you use Google's map search (not geocoder)? For instance, if I type in google maps: 1249 Cedar Rd. 101 Chesapeake VA 23322. It will return the right location, but when I do a geocoding of this address it doesn't show the right location (wrong lat/long). What I was hoping is to just use https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1249+Cedar+Rd.+101+Chesapeake+VA+23322&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x89baa4d9ad5e3b8b:0x844028b651d3e0cb,1249+Cedar+Rd,+Chesapeake,+VA+23322&gl=us&ei=IWJAUs_PHonV2AWoz4GwBw&ved=0CCwQ8gEwAA

If you click on that link, it will show the correct location. Is there a way to use PHP/JSON use the above URL?

Or, is there a way to pair Google Maps/Places, to return the right address? I'm trying to figure out a way to get the correct address. Search that works fine in google, but not when geocoding. It's really annoying....

Comment: Why would you want to use that maps service when you could use the API?  Follow this link and see that it will geocode properly to JSON http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1249%20Cedar%20Rd.%20101%20Chesapeake%20VA%2023322&sensor=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, I figured out what was going wrong. I wasn't properly encoding the address when I put it into Google, so it was returning a different address. I switched to using the php urlencode() function and it seems to be working.

Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I get the same(ish) coordinates from the Geocoding API as I do from the map: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1249%20Cedar%20Rd.%20101%20Chesapeake%20VA%2023322&sensor=false gives

```
  "lat" : 36.7174039802915,
  "lng" : -76.2835059197085
```

Which match (with very small differences) in what I get when I right click on the marker and choose **What's here** which is possibly what you mean by geocoding from the map? :

```
   36.717567,
   -76.283689
```

This puts the point right beside the location selected by Google maps. This shows that Google's internal look-up is using slightly different (better?) data then the Geocoding API but all three points show the same address. Am I missing something in how you are getting the incorrect address?

Comment: Try this address: 1464 Mt. Pleasant Rd., #118, Chesapeake, VA 23322. It will return a location in north carolina (35.55385,  -78.622126). Yet in google it returns the right address...

Comment: Not for me: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1464%20Mt.%20Pleasant%20Rd.,%20118,%20Chesapeake,%20VA%2023322&sensor=false is the same for me... `"lat" : 36.71495300000001, "lng" : -76.18765399999999`

Comment: Note there are maps and geocoding api settings that allow you to bias results to a region, but where you are providing the state / full address I don't believe this could be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

That [Google Map](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1249+Cedar+Rd.+101+Chesapeake+VA+23322&ll=36.716054,-76.284857&spn=0.003487,0.006968&hnear=1249+Cedar+Rd,+Chesapeake,+Virginia+23322&gl=us&t=m&z=18) (click on "more" then "Zoom here" on your link to get the link above) gives me 36.716054,-76.284857

The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoder](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1249%20Cedar%20Rd.%20101%20Chesapeake%20VA%2023322&geocode=1) returns:

1249 Cedar Road, Las Gaviotas Shopping Center, Chesapeake, VA 23322, USA (36.716055, -76.28485490000003)

Which looks pretty close to me...

Comment: Try this address: 1464 Mt. Pleasant Rd., #118, Chesapeake, VA 23322. It will return a location in north carolina (35.55385,  -78.622126). Yet in google it returns the right address...

Comment: What about it? The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoder returns](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1464%20Mt.%20Pleasant%20Rd.,%20%23118,%20Chesapeake,%20VA%2023322&geocode=1) 1464 Mount Pleasant Road #118, Chesapeake, VA 23322, USA (36.71495300000001, -76.187654) [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1464+Mt.+Pleasant+Rd.,+%23118,+Chesapeake,+VA+23322&hl=en&ll=36.714953,-76.187654&spn=0.001744,0.003484&sll=36.714953,-76.187654&sspn=0.01395,0.027874&hnear=1464+Mt+Pleasant+Rd+%23118,+Chesapeake,+Virginia+23322&t=m&z=19) gives 36.714953,-76.187654 looks the same to me